# Return a Nodejs Readable Stream as Response in CloudFlare Worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, cloudflare, ytdl

I am trying to send a Readable Stream as Response to a CloudFlare Worker. I am using `ytdl-core` npm module to fetch the Readable Stream.

**Here is the entry point for the worker.**

```js
const getAudio = (videoID, quality = "lowest") => {
  const audioStream = ytdl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID, {
    quality,
    filter: "audioonly",
  });
  audioStream.on("error", (e) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${e.message}`);
  });
  return audioStream;
};

const handleRequest = (request) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const videoID = url.searchParams.get("v");
  if (typeof videoID === "string") {
    const nodeStream = getAudio(videoID);
    const webStream = nodeToWebStream(nodeStream);
    let { readable, writable } = new TransformStream();
    webStream.pipeTo(writable);
    return new Response(readable, webStream);
  } else return new Response("Hello World");
};

addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});
```

**Here is the Webpack Config**

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  target: "webworker",
  entry: "./index.js",
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      ReadableStream: ["web-streams-polyfill/ponyfill", "ReadableStream"],
      ytdl: "ytdl-core",
      nodeToWebStream: "readable-stream-node-to-web",
    }),
  ],
};
```

I am converting the Nodejs Readable Stream to a Web Readable Stream and then piping it to the Writable Stream part of the Transform Stream as mentioned in the [Cloudflare Docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/using-streams).
But I am encountering an error like this:

```
TypeError: ReadableStream.prototype.pipeTo's first argument must be a WritableStream
    at e.pipeTo (worker.js:11:89436)
    at r (worker.js:9:33134)
    at worker.js:9:33241 at line 10, col 89434
{
  "exceptionDetails": {
    "columnNumber": 89434,
    "exception": {
      "className": "TypeError",
      "description": "TypeError: ReadableStream.prototype.pipeTo's first argument must be a WritableStream\n    at e.pipeTo (worker.js:11:89436)\n    at r (worker.js:9:33134)\n    at worker.js:9:33241",
      "preview": null,
      "subtype": "error",
      "type": "object",
      "value": null
    },
    "lineNumber": 10,
    "text": "Uncaught (in promise)",
    "url": "worker.js"
  },
  "timestamp": 1636696072821
}
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')
    at Object.u.request (worker.js:9:11037)
    at Object.o.request (worker.js:11:21923)
    at O (worker.js:8:27433)
    at p.run (worker.js:1:2260)
    at d (worker.js:1:1754) at line 8, col 11035
{
  "exceptionDetails": {
    "columnNumber": 11035,
    "exception": {
      "className": "TypeError",
      "description": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')\n    at Object.u.request (worker.js:9:11037)\n    at Object.o.request (worker.js:11:21923)\n    at O (worker.js:8:27433)\n    at p.run (worker.js:1:2260)\n    at d (worker.js:1:1754)",
      "preview": null,
      "subtype": "error",
      "type": "object",
      "value": null
    },
    "lineNumber": 8,
    "text": "Uncaught",
    "url": "worker.js"
  },
  "timestamp": 1636696072821
}
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol') at line 0, col -2
{
  "exceptionDetails": {
    "columnNumber": -2,
    "exception": {
      "className": "TypeError",
      "description": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')",
      "preview": null,
      "subtype": "error",
      "type": "object",
      "value": null
    },
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "text": "Uncaught (async)",
    "url": "undefined"
  },
  "timestamp": 1636696072821
}
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')
    at Object.u.request (worker.js:9:11037)
    at Object.o.request (worker.js:11:21923)
    at O (worker.js:8:27433)
    at p.run (worker.js:1:2260)
    at d (worker.js:1:1754)
    at f (worker.js:1:1662) at line 8, col 11035
{
  "exceptionDetails": {
    "columnNumber": 11035,
    "exception": {
      "className": "TypeError",
      "description": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')\n    at Object.u.request (worker.js:9:11037)\n    at Object.o.request (worker.js:11:21923)\n    at O (worker.js:8:27433)\n    at p.run (worker.js:1:2260)\n    at d (worker.js:1:1754)\n    at f (worker.js:1:1662)",
      "preview": null,
      "subtype": "error",
      "type": "object",
      "value": null
    },
    "lineNumber": 8,
    "text": "Uncaught",
    "url": "worker.js"
  },
  "timestamp": 1636696072821
}
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol') at line 0, col -2
{
  "exceptionDetails": {
    "columnNumber": -2,
    "exception": {
      "className": "TypeError",
      "description": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')",
      "preview": null,
      "subtype": "error",
      "type": "object",
      "value": null
    },
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "text": "Uncaught (async)",
    "url": "undefined"
  },
  "timestamp": 1636696072821
}
Error: The script will never generate a response. at line 0, col -2
{
  "exceptionDetails": {
    "columnNumber": -2,
    "exception": {
      "className": "Error",
      "description": "Error: The script will never generate a response.",
      "preview": {
        "description": "Error: The script will never generate a response.",
        "entries": null,
        "overflow": false,
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "stack",
            "subtype": null,
            "type": "string",
            "value": "Error: The script will never generate a response.",
            "valuePreview": null
          },
          {
            "name": "message",
            "subtype": null,
            "type": "string",
            "value": "The script will never generate a response.",
            "valuePreview": null
          }
        ],
        "subtype": "error",
        "type": "object"
      },
      "subtype": "error",
      "type": "object",
      "value": null
    },
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "text": "Uncaught (in response)",
    "url": "undefined"
  },
  "timestamp": 1636696073821
}
```

Any help is Appreciated.